# Searching in a listBox using backgroundWorker

Tags: c#, winforms, search, listbox, backgroundworker

**This is a C# - WinForm question:**
I'm trying to search in a listBox. There's ONLY ONE listBox full of some items. On program load, all the items in the listBox, get copied into a List of type string called 'tempList'. 
There's also a TextBox. When the user starts to type in the TextBox, the listBox gets cleared using the Clear() method. After that, the word in the textbox will be searched in the tempList using a foreach block. Every match will be added to the listBox and shown to the user. 
I came up with this code:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Clear();
        foreach (string item in tempList)
        {
            if (item.ToLower().Contains(textBox1.Text.ToLower()))
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(item);
            }
        }
    }
```

**The problem** is, that when the user starts to type into the textbox, with the FIRST character, the UI breaks and user has to wait until the search for that one character is done and then they can type again and this happens with every character. To solve this I figured out that I can use backgroundWorker. But I don't understand how to use it for this scenario. Anything helpful will be appreciated.

Comment: It seems that you are trying to replicate the AutoComplete feature with a different interface. Why don't you use the already built in UI functionality?

Comment: I guess the Auto Completion is the one that suggests words as the user is typing and appends to the content of a textbox? No that's not my intention. I'm specifically trying to search in a listBox for a word typed in a textbox.

Comment: You should start searching only after user leave textbox or press `enter`.

Comment: @Fabio That is a good idea. Using a button and pressing Enter actually did cross my mind but I really would like to use backgroundWorker and do the search as the user is typing. Because I have seen this way of searching in many applications. For example, the music player 'Winamp' has a very similar search box and it's really easy to use. The results get filtered down more and more as I type in the box, until I see what I want and I stop typing. I wanted to create something like that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the BackgroundWorker class...

declare...

```
    BackgroundWorker listSearch = new BackgroundWorker();
```

initialize...

```
        listSearch.DoWork += ListSearch_DoWork;
        listSearch.RunWorkerCompleted += ListSearch_RunWorkerCompleted;
```

event handler implementation...

```
    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listSearch.RunWorkerAsync(textBox1.Text);
    }

    private void ListSearch_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        string text = e.Argument as string;
        List<string> items = new List<string>();
        foreach (string item in tempList)
        {
            if (item.ToLower().Contains(text.ToLower()))
            {
                items.Add(item);
            }
        }
        e.Result = items.ToArray();
    }

   private void ListSearch_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        string[] items = e.Result as string[];
        Invoke((Action)(() =>
        {
            listBox1.Items.Clear();
            foreach(string item in items)
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(item);
            }
        }));
    }
```

Comment: Amazing! That Works EXACTLY like what I wanted to. Can't thank you enough.

Comment: Note: the invoke in the run worker completed handler is superfluous.  I just did a quick check and the run worker completed always runs on the same thread on which the background worker was created.  So you can simplify a bit.

Answer (score 1):

The use of the `Task` class is much easier than the `BackgroundWorker`.

Try this simple solution:

```
private async void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listBox.DataSource = null;

    var task = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            var resultList = new List<string>();

            foreach (string item in tempList)
                if (item.ToLower().Contains(textBox.Text.ToLower()))
                    resultList.Add(item);

            return resultList;
        });

    listBox.DataSource = await task;
}
```

Use data binding to simplify the code. On program load, set

```
listBox.DataSource = tempList;
```